# Expo Route connected to Firebase Dynamic Links or Branch.io

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, branch.io

I'm trying to find documentation on how you can implement Dynamic Links with Firebase or Brannch.io using Expo Route.

I have an structure where a page can be visited directly from the routes that I built in my expo route structure, but I don't know what are the next steps to make this work.

I have been trying to find a video, tutorial or more documentation but I can't find anything.

Please, that will help me a lot!

Thanks.
Nico.